# IAM policy to grant access only to Amazon aliased keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

In [KMS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html) there are the amazon aliased keys (e.g.`/alias/aws/s3`) and [Customer Master Keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#master_keys) (CMKs).

For each development team, I have a few CMKs with aliases (e.g. `/alias/team1/default`, `/alias/team1/confidential`)

I'd like to allow access to the aws aliased keys to all IAM users/groups/roles, but provide team level access to team level keys

My issue comes when trying to allow access to aws managed keys

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "NotAction": [
        "iam:*",
        "kms:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": "false"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111111111111:alias/aws/*",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": "false"
        }
      }  
    }
  ]
}
```

To provide implicit deny to `iam:*` and `kms:*`, but allow access to aws aliased Keys

When working with the IAM policy simulator, it looks like I have to provide access to the full key arn (`arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111111111111:key/abcd123-acbd-1234-abcd-acbcd1234abcd`) rather than the alias (`arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:111111111111:alias/aws/*`)

Is there a better way to manage this?

I know I can manage access to CMKs using key policies and not allow access from IAM, but you can't use groups as a `Principal` in a KMS key policy

Comment: Be careful with the NotAction element. In your example policy you have granted all services and actions that are NOT iam:* and kms:*. Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notaction.html

Comment: This is for our dev account and the group I'm making this for is a 'poweruser' group. The idea is they should have the ability to try things and experiment without friction, but should a team decide to encrypt with their own keys, I want the key access isolated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use key alias as the resource for APIs which are used to control access to APIs that act on the Aliases themselves (e.g. Create/Delete Alias) and an alias can not be used as ARN in place of a Key ID to control access to the underlying keys. You can refer to the table in the following URL which explains which resource/ARN to use with KMS APIs.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/kms-api-permissions-reference.html

You can consider this approach: Allow the IAM Group to assume an IAM role and allow the IAM role in the CMK's key policy.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=173540

Answer (score 13):

While I know the issue is resolved, I am tempted to posting this from the best source.

An alias cannot be used within policies
Refer the following passage from https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-kms-best-practices.pdf

> It should be noted that CMK aliases can’t be used within policies.
>   This is because the mapping of aliases to keys can be manipulated
>   outside the policy, which would allow for an escalation of privilege.
>   Therefore, key IDs must be used in KMS key policies, IAM policies, and
>   KMS grants